# How to intercet $httpBackend calls and add a token verify middleware in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular's $httpBackend to mock a backend.

Is there a way to intercept every request to the $httpBackend in order to verify a token?

Right now, I can do this in every url call, like bellow - but I want to simulate a middleware, so I won't need to do this for every url request, if for example I'll have 10.

angular.module('app').run(['$httpBackend', 'MoviesDataModel', function($httpBackend, MoviesDataModel) {

```
    $httpBackend.whenPOST('/movies').respond(function(method, url, data, headers) {

        // Check the X-AUTH-TOKEN value.
        var authToken = headers['X-AUTH-TOKEN'];

        // If we have a auth token
        if (authToken === 'headervalue') {
            // Check if the token is valid.
            var params = angular.fromJson(data),
                movie = MoviesDataModel.addOne(params),
                movieId = movie.id; // get the id of the new resource to populate the Location field
            return [201, movie, { Location: '/movies/' + movieId }];
        } else {
            // 401 Unauthorize - The user is not logged in.
            return [401, '', {}];
        }
    });

    $httpBackend.whenGET(/\.html$/).passThrough();

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [decorator](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#decorator) to intercept all calls to `$httpBackend` and do whatever you want with them.

```
angular.module('http-app')
 .config(['$provide',
   function($provide) {

     $provide.decorator('$httpBackend', function($delegate) {

       var interceptedCalls = [],

         //Create a new function that will proxy calls to
         // the  $httpBackend service
         newHttpBackend = function(method, url, post, callback, headers, 
                                   timeout, withCredentials, responseType) {

           //Trivial example of tracking each call
           // and a timestamp
           interceptedCalls.push({
             method: method,
             url: url,
             timestamp: new Date()
           });

           //Now call the original with all the arguments
           return $delegate(method, url, post, callback, headers, 
                            timeout, withCredentials, responseType);

         };

       newHttpBackend.interceptedCalls = interceptedCalls;

       //Return the proxy function
       return newHttpBackend;

     });
   }
]);
```